# How to make a discord.py reaction role code

Tags: discord.py

I'm new to discord bot making, and I'd like to have the bot add a reaction to my message that, once pressed, allows the user reacting to pick up a role. What would be the code to allow me to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very well written and formatted question! In order for the bot to detect that the reaction is on a specific message, you can do many ways. The easiest way would be to be by ID, so I'm just going to do this with a simple command.

```
messageIDs = []

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    global messageIDs

    for messageID in messageIDs:
        if messageID == payload.message_id:
            user = payload.member
            role = "roleName"
            await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name = role))

@client.command()
async def addMessage(ctx, messageID):
    global messageIDs
    
    emoji = ""
    channel = ctx.message.channel

    try:
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(messageID)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Invalid Message ID!")
        return
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
    messageIDs.append(messageID)
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but here's my code - https://gyazo.com/84543de0d7544646c499861469ffa4e3. However, it says this when I run the bot:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james\Desktop\CustomBot.py", line 18, in <module>
    @client.event
NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the code a bit and got it to run, but it's not adding a reaction or doing anything when people react.

https://gyazo.com/43eaf3cebb013fa62e5ba1b414de8519 is my code, but the reaction isn't doing anything

Comment: Sorry about that, my code had a lot of errors. I've edited my code and it should be good now!

Comment: Sorry again, but do I need to import anything at the beginning other than `discord`, and `from discord.ext import commands`? I say this because this is the code I have set up - https://gyazo.com/60a88b1fabd762f1430319a304e97c01, however when I run the code, it says this: https://gyazo.com/d94d2fc46c73b97f30dbf6cc3b92ee98. Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to import discord utils as so: ```from discord.utils import get``` Sorry for the late response!